# Natural key for sign polarity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, boolean, natural-key

A many-to-many table joins two entity tables.  I need an additional column in the many-to-many table to represent polarity and it should only have two values where one represents positive and the second represents negative.

To implement this, I plan on adding a table called `sign` which will have a single column called `sign` (which is also the table's primary key), and the table will contain only two values where one represents positive and the other represents negative.

The aforementioned many-to-many table can then include `sign.sign` as a foreign keys, and only the two values will be allowed.

If this is a poor solution, please comment why you feel this way and what might be a better solution.

If an acceptable solution, then what should the two values be?  Possible answers are:

- positive and negative (will not be using)
- p and n (probably not)
- 1 and 0
- 1 and -1

I've purposely included the `php` tag to indicate that I will be using PHP on the chance that one solution over the other may simplify PHP implementation.

Comment: Are the down votes and close votes because it is opinion based or because one shouldn't store polarity in a DB, or some other reason?  Thanks

Comment: Three votes on unclear. Can't you see the votes on your own question?

Comment: @Andreas  I see the `close (3)` but no, I can't see the reason.  Where do you see it?  I will take steps to make more clear.  Thanks

Comment: @Andreas  I've edited the original question.  Do you feel it is less unclear now?

Comment: I have not voted, I just answered your question, what the close votes was.

Comment: @Andreas  Wasn't implying you did.  Regardless, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not strictly a fan of `bit`, but something like this should do what you want and be clear:

```
create table . . . (
    . . . 
    sign_is_positive bit(1) not null,
    . . . 
)
```

Another method is to use a `check` constraint, which the more recent versions of MariaDB support.  I might be inclined to do:

```
create table . . . (
    . . . 
    sign char(1) not null,
    . . . 
    constraint chk_t_sign check sign (sign in ('+', '-'))
)
```

Personally, I think the best symbols for "positive" and "negative" and `+` and `-`.

Comment: Any specific reasons you don't care for `bit`?  Also, do you recommend `check` over my foreign key solution?  Yes, using `+` and `-` is definitely intuitive (don't know why I didn't think of them!),  and I will likely use.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 . . . I associate a lot of overhead with bits, because of all the bit fiddling involved.  Also, in databases, bits don't necessary save much space and definitely not time.  They are often a sign of micro-optimizations focused on the wrong areas.

Answer (score 1):

If one wishes to use the sign in arithmetic within a query, then 1/-1 might be the best choice.